# javascript es6 destructuring

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I understand that you can destructure function parameters. Is there a way to have the object variable as well as the destructured properties of the object? example below

```
function updateUser(user: { id, name }) {
    update(user, where: { id });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a variable to the end of the destructured list and that turns into your object name essentially:

```
Const obj = {a: 1, b:2, c:3}
Const { a, b, ...rest } = obj
rest.c === 3 //true
```

Comment: I'd include that `const { a, b, ...rest } = obj` is called [rest syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) and its part of [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: `Const obj = {a: 1, b:2, c:3}` is not valid javascript as far as I know.

Comment: How is it not? What isn’t valid about it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can, that's violating the purpose of object destruction.
But instead, you can do it like this if you really want the original object.

```
function updateUser(user) {
    const { name, id } = user;
    update(user, { id });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [immutable-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) instead. This library allows you to update your object using a syntax (inspired by MongoDB's query syntax) like your explanation on your question.